# Creating an identifier class for a Parsetree

Tags: c++, class, parsing

for an assignment of mine we are creating a recursive descent parser based on the grammar rules below:

```
Prog ::= StmtList

StmtList ::= { Stmt T_SC } { StmtList }

Stmt ::= Decl | Set | Print

Decl ::= T_INT T_ID | T_STRING T_ID

Set ::= T_SET T_ID Expr

Print ::= T_PRINT Expr | T_PRINTLN Expr

Expr ::= Term { (T_PLUS|T_MINUS) Expr }

Term ::= Primary { (T_STAR|T_SLASH) Term }

Primary ::= T_ICONST | T_SCONST | T_ID | T_LPAREN Expr T_RPAREN
```

My question is, I am currently working on the Decl function of the Parsetree, I am stuck on how to create a class in my header file that will recognize identifiers. I just want to know how to create a class for Decl function. That is all. And please if you are going to downvote my question, explain to me why so that I may learn and implement. I have included below the header file and only the Decl function from the parse.cpp file.

```
ParseTree * Decl(istream* in) { // Needs Fixing
//Decl ::= T_INT T_ID | T_STRING T_ID
   Token tok1 = ParserToken.getToken(in);
    cout << "token in Decl: " << tok1 << endl;
      if(tok1 == T_INT)
      {
        Token tok2 = ParserToken.getToken(in);
         if(tok2 != T_ID)
         {
            error(tok2.GetLinenum(), "Identifier Required");
            return 0;
         }
         return new Declare(tok1.GetLinenum(), "T_INT",0);
      }
      else if(tok1 == T_STRING)
      {
        Token tok3 = ParserToken.getToken(in);
         if(tok3 != T_ID)
         {
            error(tok3.GetLinenum(), "Identifier Required");
            return 0;
         }
         return new Declare(tok1.GetLinenum(), "T_STRING", 0);
      }
     else 
        ParserToken.pushbackToken(tok1);


   return 0;
}
```

**Header File**

```
#ifndef PARSER_H_
#define PARSER_H_

#include <iostream>
using std::istream;

#include <string>
using std::string;
using std::stoi;

#include "lexer.h"

extern void error(int linenum, const string& message);

extern int idcount, setcount, mcount, pcount;

enum TypeForNode { INT_TYPE, STRING_TYPE, ERROR_TYPE };

class ParseTree {
    int         linenumber;
    ParseTree   *left;
    ParseTree   *right;

public:
    ParseTree(int n, ParseTree *l = 0, ParseTree *r = 0) : linenumber(n), left(l), right(r) {}
    virtual ~ParseTree() {}

    ParseTree* getLeft() const { return left; }
    ParseTree* getRight() const { return right; }
    int getLineNumber() const { return linenumber; }

    virtual TypeForNode GetType() const { return ERROR_TYPE; }
    virtual int GetIntValue() const { throw "no integer value"; }
    virtual string GetStringValue() const { throw "no string value"; }
};

class StatementList : public ParseTree {
public:
    StatementList(ParseTree *first, ParseTree *rest) : ParseTree(0, first, rest) {}

};
class Addition : public ParseTree {
public:
    Addition(int line, ParseTree *op1, ParseTree *op2) : ParseTree(line, op1, op2) {}

};


class Subtraction : public ParseTree {
public:
    Subtraction(int line, ParseTree *op1, ParseTree *op2) : ParseTree(line, op1, op2) {}

    // will need to fill in type and value;
    // remember type is a function of
};
class Multiplication : public ParseTree {
public:
    Multiplication(int line, ParseTree *op1, ParseTree *op2) : ParseTree(line, op1, op2) {}

    // will need to fill in type and value;
    // remember type is a function of
};
class Division : public ParseTree {
public:
    Division(int line, ParseTree *op1, ParseTree *op2) : ParseTree(line, op1, op2) {}

    // will need to fill in type and value;
    // remember type is a function of
};
class PrintStatement : public ParseTree {
public: 
   PrintStatement(int line, ParseTree *op1) : ParseTree(line, op1, 0){}
};
class Declare : public ParseTree { //This is where I'm having trouble
   string id;
public: 
   Declare(int line, ParseTree *op1) : ParseTree(line, op1, 0){
       TypeForNode GetType() const { return STRING_TYPE; }
       string GetStringValue() const { return id; }
   }
};
class StringConstant : public ParseTree {
   string value;
public: 
   StringConstant(const Token& tok) : ParseTree(tok.GetLinenum()) {
      value = stoi( tok.GetLexeme() );
   }

   TypeForNode GetType() const { return STRING_TYPE; }
   string GetStringValue() const { return value; }
};
class IntegerConstant : public ParseTree {
    int value;
public:
    IntegerConstant(const Token& tok) : ParseTree(tok.GetLinenum()) {
        value = stoi( tok.GetLexeme() );
    }

    TypeForNode GetType() const { return INT_TYPE; }
    int GetIntValue() const { return value; }
};

extern ParseTree *  Prog(istream* in);
extern ParseTree *  StmtList(istream* in);
extern ParseTree *  Stmt(istream* in);
extern ParseTree *  Decl(istream* in);
extern ParseTree *  Set(istream* in);
extern ParseTree *  Print(istream* in);
extern ParseTree *  Expr(istream* in);
extern ParseTree *  Term(istream* in);
extern ParseTree *  Primary(istream* in);

#endif /* PARSER_H_ */
```

These are the errors I am receiving, which all revolve around the same lines.

```
arser.h: In constructor ‘Declare::Declare(int, ParseTree*)’:                                                                                    
parser.h:85:32: error: a function-definition is not allowed here before ‘{’ token                                                                
    TypeForNode GetType() const { return STRING_TYPE; }                                                                                          
                                ^                                                                                                                
parser.h:86:34: error: a function-definition is not allowed here before ‘{’ token                                                                
    string GetStringValue() const { return id; }                                                                                                 
                                  ^                                                                                                              
In file included from parser.cpp:9:0:                                                                                                            
parser.h: In constructor ‘Declare::Declare(int, ParseTree*)’:                                                                                    
parser.h:85:32: error: a function-definition is not allowed here before ‘{’ token                                                                
    TypeForNode GetType() const { return STRING_TYPE; }                                                                                          
                                ^                                                                                                                
parser.h:86:34: error: a function-definition is not allowed here before ‘{’ token                                                                
    string GetStringValue() const { return id; }                                                                                                 
                                  ^                                                                                                              
parser.cpp: In function ‘ParseTree* Decl(std::istream*)’:                                                                                        
parser.cpp:84:57: error: no matching function for call to ‘Declare::Declare(int, const char [6], int)’                                           
          return new Declare(tok1.GetLinenum(), "T_INT",0);                                                                                      
                                                         ^                                                                                       
In file included from parser.cpp:9:0:                                                                                                            
parser.h:84:4: note: candidate: Declare::Declare(int, ParseTree*)                                                                                
    Declare(int line, ParseTree *op1) : ParseTree(line, op1, 0){                                                                                 
    ^                                                                                                                                            
parser.h:84:4: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 3 provided                                                                                 
parser.h:81:7: note: candidate: Declare::Declare(const Declare&)                                                                                 
 class Declare : public ParseTree {                                                                                                              
       ^                                                                                                                                         
parser.h:81:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 3 provided                                                                                  
parser.h:81:7: note: candidate: Declare::Declare(Declare&&)                                                                                      
parser.h:81:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 3 provided                                                                                  
parser.cpp:94:61: error: no matching function for call to ‘Declare::Declare(int, const char [9], int)’                                           
          return new Declare(tok1.GetLinenum(), "T_STRING", 0);                                                                                  
                                                             ^
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what you mean by "create a class for Decl function"? Isn't that the `Declare` class you already have? What problems do you have with it? Do you get build error (which I guess you do)? If so then edit your question to *show* these errors to us. Copy them, in full and complete, as text. Then paste them, without modifications, into the question body.

Comment: Yes it is the Declare class I currently have, i'm just having trouble with it as im doing it wrong.

Comment: I've edited your question to add some indentation in the `Declare` class. That should hopefully make some of the errors clearer.